# Export images Dbeaver - Postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, image, format, export, dbeaver

I have a number of images that are stored in a postgresql database. When I use the tools to export the data, I cannot choose a image format like png/jpeg. Is there a way to do it or can I do it with a script ?

This all the format available on the DBeaver platform:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: What tools are 'the tools'?  PostgreSQL itself is certainly a database management system, not an image conversion library.

Comment: The tools from Dbeaver, there are some options in the interface to export data. But none of them is suited for images, but rather tables/numbers

Comment: All I see under "[Database]->[tools]" is session manager, lock manager, and create new task.  I wouldn't expect those to offer image conversion.  Also DBeaver is not an image conversion library, so I would not expect it to offer that service at all unless maybe you can find some plug in.  If these things were not in a database in the first place, how would you convert them?

Comment: I attached a screenshot of the options I obtain through the Dbeaver platform, and after trying all of them, none of them is really suited for an image. 
Besides that, is there any way to export the images through an SQL query ?

Comment: Have you found a solutio? i am having the same problem

Answer (score 1):

In the table-specific "Export Data" menu, under "Format Settings", there is an drop box for "Binaries" with a choice of "Save to Files".  This will save the vales from bytea columns to individual files.  It will save them in whatever format they are in in the database, but once saved you can process them with the tool of your choice.